# How croston method should be applied to dataset

Tags: r, forecast

I have dataset which shows monthly demands for 250 products.

 I imported the data in R.I want to apply croston method this dataset and write the results on file but i don't know how i can apply formula row by row and write to the file. Ihave table like this:

```
     product   D1 D2 D3 D3 D4....
     DV400767  6  1  3  1 17  0  5  0   0   1   0   3   0
     DV557119  6  3  2  1 16  0  0  0   0   0   1   0  10
     DV596323  0  0  2  1  2  0  2  9   0   3   0   0   2
```

I am trying to find the result by these code but crost function is just applied one column

```
data<-read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE)
crost(data, h=1,w=0.3, init=c(1,1))
```

I know I have mistakes, how can I improve the function?Or do I need to create a loop?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please look at [ask] to learn how to ask a good question which will get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose your `data.frame` and use `apply` function:

```
data <- read.table(text = "
DV400767  6  1  3  1 17  0  5  0   0   1   0   3   0
DV557119  6  3  2  1 16  0  0  0   0   0   1   0  10
DV596323  0  0  2  1  2  0  2  9   0   3   0   0   2")
names(data) <- c("product", paste0("D", 1:13))

rownames(data) <- data$product
data_t <- as.data.frame(t(data[, -1]))

library(tsintermittent)
models <- apply(data_t, 2, crost, h = 1, w = 0.3, init = c(1,1))

# Print information of the fist product: DV400767
list(names(data_t)[1], models[[1]])
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "DV400767"

[[2]]
[[2]]$`model`
[1] "croston"

[[2]]$frc.in
 [1]          NA 2.750000178 2.531250137 2.602272849 2.317170902 5.293018040 5.293018040 4.268771415 4.268771415 4.268771415
[11] 2.537046096 2.537046096 2.230787775

[[2]]$frc.out
[1] 2.230787775

[[2]]$weights
[1] 0.3 0.3

[[2]]$initial
[1] 8.249999748 2.999999714

[[2]]$components
[[2]]$components$`c.in`
           Demand    Interval
 [1,]          NA          NA
 [2,] 8.249999748 2.999999714
 [3,] 6.074999823 2.399999800
 [4,] 5.152499876 1.979999860
 [5,] 3.906749913 1.685999902
 [6,] 7.834724939 1.480199931
 [7,] 7.834724939 1.480199931
 [8,] 6.984307458 1.636139952
 [9,] 6.984307458 1.636139952
[10,] 6.984307458 1.636139952
[11,] 5.189015220 2.045297966
[12,] 5.189015220 2.045297966
[13,] 4.532310654 2.031708576

[[2]]$components$c.out
          Demand    Interval
[1,] 4.532310654 2.031708576

[[2]]$components$coeff
[1] 1
```